# Update trigger, add not working properly

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert-update

Sorry in advance for my English, here is the problem: as I can not to think about the logic of the trigger, the bottom line is that there are 2 tables:

- material list
- the arrival Journal

When adding records to a table in the magazine of the parish shall operate a trigger which checks if the table is empty add a new entry (Material, quantity in stock), if the table has records then update them on the condition that the `Material = (select the part Name From inserted)`, but if the table has records and `Material != select the part Name From inserted)` then add a new record.

Here is the code of the trigger:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Trigger [dbo].[Application Log Sheet] 
ON [dbo].[Parish magazine]
FOR INSERT 
AS
     DECLARE @a INT;
     DECLARE @b int;

     SELECT @a = COUNT(*) 
     FROM Bill of materials 

     IF @a > 0
     BEGIN
         UPDATE Vedomostithe
         SET Kolichestvennogo = the Number of stock + (select Quantity from inserted)
         WHERE Material = (select the part Name from inserted)
     END
     ELSE IF @a >= 0 
        INSERT INTO Bill of material(Material, Quantity in stock)
            SELECT the part Name, Number
            FROM the arrival Journal
            WHERE [ID] IN (SELECT [ID] FROM inserted)
```

Table bill of materials:

```
create table Bill of materials 
(
     ID int primary key,
     Material nvarchar(max),
     Quantity in stock int
)
```

Table arrival journal:

```
create table Journal of the parish
(
     ID int primary key,
     Part name nvarchar(max),
     The number of int
)
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you targetting?

Comment: I have the version of sql Server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand, you shouldn't *store* data that can be *calculated*, since all that does is give you an opportunity for the stored calculation to be inconsistent with the rest of the data. As such, I'd usually recommend just having a view that shows the totals.

On the other hand, this looks like a straightforward task for [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb510625.aspx). But we need to bear in mind that `inserted` can contain *multiple* rows, and these could be for multiple different parts. So, we want something like:

```
ALTER Trigger [dbo].[Application Log Sheet] 
ON [dbo].[Parish magazine]
for insert
AS

MERGE INTO [Bill of Materials] t
USING (SELECT PART, SUM(Quantity) as Qty from inserted group by PART) s
ON t.Part = s.Part
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Quantity = t.Quantity + s.Qty
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Part,Quantity) VALUES (s.Part,s.Qty)
```

Apologies if some of the names are incorrect above, but hopefully you can see how to adapt it to fit your requirements (you questions seems to flip-flop between various table/column names such that there seem to be about four different table names, whereas you start your question by saying that there are two).

Comment: Thank you very much!now I know about the MERGE!